# Why always get month=0 in as.period (lubridate package) in R

Tags: r, lubridate

Using the `as.period` I like to know the exact difference in year, month and date. However, I always get month value equal to zero and it transforms the month into date as following:

```
library(lubridate)
 as.period((dmy("01/06/1981")- dmy("30/07/1979")),units="year")
estimate only: convert difftimes to intervals for accuracy
[1] "1y 0m 306d 18H 0M 0S"
```

How can I get the corresponding month as well?
And how can I format output which does not show hour, minute and second?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interval, then coerce it to a `period`:

```
library(lubridate)
ii <- new_interval(dmy("01/05/1981"),dmy("30/07/1979"))
as.period(ii,units="months")
[1] "-21m -1d 0H 0M 0S"

res <- as.period(ii,units="years")
[1] "-1y -9m -1d 0H 0M 0S"
```

#### EDIT

I don't think that you can remove the hour,minutes parts. But you can write your print function:

```
paste0(c(res@year,res@month,res@day),c('y','m','d'),collapse=' ')
"-1y -9m -1d"
```

Comment: @agstudy: i read this way too quickly. deleted my comment. sorry about that.

Comment: `new_interval` is deprecated

Comment: it is `interval` instead